# Remove all iAds app wide?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, iad

I've added in app purchases to remove iAds for my iOS app.

I've put this in the logic once the removeAds product is bought (which definitely triggers):

```
func removeAds() {
    defaults.setObject("True", forKey: "remove_adverts")
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = false
    self.removeAdButton.enabled = false
    println("removed")
}
```

And I've put this at the top of each controller to handle it.

```
if let showAds = defaults.dataForKey("remove_adverts") {
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = false
    self.removeAdButton.enabled = false
    println("Ads shouldn't show")
} else {
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
}
```

But the ads still show.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean, "top of each controller"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're checking to see if the user has purchased the IAP to remove ads in this line `if let showAds = defaults.dataForKey("remove_adverts")` you're checking for `dataForKey` when you should be checking for `objectForKey` because you used `setObject` when setting your `default` value. Alternatively, you could use `setBool` so your code would look something like this:

```
func removeAds() {
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "removeAdsPurchased")
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = false
    println("iAd removed and default value set")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

and

```
    let showAds = defaults.boolForKey("removeAdsPurchased")
    if (showAds) {
        // User purchsed IAP
        // Lets remove ads
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = false
        println("iAd removed")
    } else {
        // IAP not purchased
        // Lets show some ads
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        println("Showing iAd")
    }
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly. Thanks